# casper.then does not wait the end of my instruction to execute the next step

Tags: casperjs

I have made this little test:

```
casper.test.begin('Test', function() {
casper.start();

casper.then(function() {
    casper = this;
    setTimeout(function(casper) {
        casper.echo('wait 5s');
    }, 5000);
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.echo('should appear after 5s');
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.test.done();
});
});
```

When I execute this test, my console shows only this line "should appear after 5s" but not the first sentence, in fact the second 'then' does not wait for 5 seconds.

It's a huge problem because it's the possible cause of many random failure in my casperjs test suite.

Maybe I have to use async (with series) to execute each step after the other.

Do you have this problem ? What's the best practice to execute some javascript functions one after the other in casperjs tests ?

Answer (score 6):

Try to use [**wait()**](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#wait) here:

```
casper.then(function() {
    casper = this;
    casper.echo('wait 5s');
});

casper.then(function() {
    casper.wait(5000, function() {
        this.echo('should appear after 5s');
    });
});
```

Comment: It was just an example, dont forget that you never have to wait(some amount of time). Its not agile for UI test, you have to wait specific events, the purpose here was to underline the failure and non stability of casper.then function. I loose my time with this function because it cannot wait the result of my functions I have to use another method I will show you

Answer (score 0):

"What's the best practice to execute some javascript functions one after the other in casperjs tests ?"

Here how i do :

login.js

```
casper.login = function (id,password) {
    casper.then(function(){ //or this.then(...)
        this.test.comment('----------------Connexion Only ! : --------------------');
        if (!this.visible('#div_boxhover')) {
            this.echo('Connexion box not visible before mouse on it!');
        }
        this.mouse.move(x('//*[@id="identification"]'));
        if (this.visible('#div_boxhover')) {
            this.echo('Connexion box visible after mouse on it!');
        } else { this.echo("FAIL : Connexion box doesn't appear");}
        //this.echo("I can see the logo");
        this.fill(x('//*[@id="div_boxhover"][1]'), { 
                login: id, 
                pass: password
            }, false);
        this.click(x('//*[@name="log_in"]'));
        this.waitForSelector(('.boxValid'), function() {
                this.test.assertSelectorHasText('.boxValid', 'Vous êtes identifié en tant que Membre !');
                this.test.assertTextExists('Succès', 'Page contains "succès" : so identification done');    
            }); 
    });
};
```

scenario1.js

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

phantom.injectJs( 'C:/bin/Aptana_casperjs/ccm/_functions/login.js');

casper.test.begin('\n********* Stack title : ***********\n', 3 , function suite(test) {
    casper.start(yourUrl,function(){
        //check one main element in the page
        this.test.assertExists('.search','Search toolbar present');
    })
    //set a viewport (for slimerJS)
    .viewport(1200,800)
    //call an external function
    .then(function() {
        casper.login("pseudo","password");//this.login("pseudo","password");
    })  
    //then click on a link + fill the form which appears
    .thenClick('div.colMiddle > a.button', function(){
        this.fillSelectors('form#frmqa', {
                'select[name="cat"]' : "2",
                'input[name="titre"]' : title,
                'textarea[name="message"]' : message
                }, false);
        this.click('input#submitqa');
    })  
    //wait for the redirection after a click at the end of a step
    .waitForText(topic, function() {
        this.test.assertSelectorHasText('.boxTitle', 'Mes discussions suivies', "New topic in 'Mes dicussions suivies'");
        this.test.assertExists('a[actid="shqafrm"].button','Button answer topic present');
    })
    //click on a new link
    .thenClick('a[actid="shqafrm"].button', function(){
        //wait for the textarea to appear
        this.waitForSelector('textarea[name="message"]',function(){
            //send message and submit
            this.sendKeys('textarea[name="message"]', newPost);
            this.click('input#submitqa');
        });
    })
    //check redirection or validation after a click on button/form/link
    .waitForSelector('.article',function(){
        test.assertTextExists(newPost, 'Answer in topic ' + title + ' done');
    })
    .run(function() {
            this.test.comment('----------------------- Stack title over ------------------------\n');
            test.done();
    });
});
```

So i just call my functions in a new step.